# Is there an effiecient and pythonic way compare day name and output of isoweekday()?

Tags: python, weekday

I want to convert these acronyms of weekdays to the weekday numbers as associated by the isoweekday()  function. Right now the code works fine but I'm searching for more effiecient way to do this.

```
if day == "sun": day = "0"
    if day == "mon": day = "1"
    if day == "tue": day = "2"
    if day == "wed": day = "3"
    if day == "thu": day = "4"
    if day == "fri": day = "5"
    if day == "sat": day = "6"
```

Comment: Make a list of the daynames and find it in the list (bearing in mind that the first list entry will have index 0)

Comment: Make you current code more efficient by using `elif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of conditions:

```
weekday = {"sun": "0", "mon": "1", "tue": "2", "wed": "3", "thu": "4", "fri": "5", "sat": "6"}
```

And access by key, for example:

```
day = weekday["sun"]
```

Comment: thank you very much kind internet stranger

Comment: Hi @BrawlStars if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: thanks for the info. I was unaware of these things. will keep in mind for future questions